# UIDatePicker mode/style

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

Does someone know what kind of format I get back when I set my DatePicker to Date and Time?

Is it equal to `NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle`?

Or is it different?

Appartently it is not this one: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Comment: Which type of format do you need?

Comment: The one that UIDatePicker gives back.

Answer (score 0):

You get instance of `NSDate` class.

You can set up from it any format that you need:

```
let myDate = datePicker.date
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let dateInString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDate)

print(dateInString)

//prints smthng like 2016-06-06T15:20:53+0300
```